# combining 4 octets of signed values and 1 byte of unsigned values together to perform a particular function

Tags: c

i need to allot a function for 4 octets and another function for 1 byte and i need to combine them together in the end. I have worked on signed values and unsigned values separately but no idea as to how to combine them for a particular application. How do i do this?

[image]

Comment: Could you show with digits what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: i have added the picture above.

Comment: This is still impossible to answer. Do you have the data as an array of bytes, as a 64 bit chunk, or something else? Or is the goal to get a bit field out of various data?

Comment: maybe think about a union

Answer (score 0):

Your image in crude ASCII art:

```
| MSB 5  |     4  |    3   |    2   |    1   | LSB 0  |
|     ACTIVE ELECTRICAL ENERGY      | TARIFF |VALIDITY|
|vvvvvvvv|vvvvvvvv|vvvvvvvv|vvvvvvvv|uuuuuuuu|rrrrrrbb|
```

Supposing you have all those bits in `allbits`, do

```
unsigned v = allbits >> 16;
unsigned u = (allbits >> 8) & 0xff;
unsigned r = (allbits >> 2) & 0x3f
unsigned b = allbits & 0x03;
```

Or the other way around, building `allbits` from the parts

```
allbits = (v << 16) | (u << 8) | (r << 2) | (b);
```

Comment: The data appears to be a 32 bit number? You should use `uint32_t`.

Comment: `v` fits a 32-bit number, `allbits` needs at least 48 bits.